# BroadCast Receiver not receive intent from Service, Background start not allowed - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver

I have a activity and a foreground service, they are separate applications (Service App has no Activity). I try to send data from service to activity with BroadcastReceiver, but it didn't receive the intent. How to pass data from service to activity ?

I assume that adding `receiver` in Manifest is unnecessary. Similar questions are not in Kotlin and mostly outdated.

**Activity**

```
class SaleActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

class MyReceiver: BroadcastReceiver(){
    override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
        if (p1!=null){
            val responseCode = p1.getStringExtra("RESPONSE_CODE")
        }
    }
}
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    val filter = IntentFilter("com.myexample.saleapp.TO_SALE_APP")
    val receiver: MyReceiver = MyReceiver()
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter)
}
}
```

**Service**

```
class RegistryService : Service(){
internal class IncomingHandler(
    context: Context,
    private val applicationContext: Context = context.applicationContext,
) : Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    override fun handleMessage(msg: Message){
        when (msg.what) {
            MSG_GO_SALE -> {
                //Intent to BroadcastReceiver
                val i = Intent()
                i.action = "com.myexample.saleapp.TO_SALE_APP"
                i.putExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", 99)
                i.flags = Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES
                i.component = ComponentName("com.myexample.saleapp","com.myexample.saleapp.SaleActivity.MyReceiver")
                applicationContext.sendBroadcast(i)
}
            else -> super.handleMessage(msg)
        }
    }
...
}
```

**Edit Service For Notification**

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    createNotificationChannel()
    startForeground(notificationId, notification)
    val i = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.myexample.paymentapp")
    if (i!=null) {
        i.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        i.putExtra("PRODUCT_ID", productId)
        i.putExtra("PRODUCT_NAME", productName)
        i.putExtra("PRICE", price)
        i.putExtra("VAT_RATE", vatRate)
        startActivity(i)
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    return START_STICKY
}
private fun createNotificationChannel() {
    val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel("progress_channel", "Progress", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
    val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
}
private val notification by lazy {
    NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "progress_channel")
        .setContentTitle("Processing payment ...")
        .setSmallIcon(R .drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
        .build()
}

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    createNotificationChannel()
    startForeground(notificationId, notification)
}
```

**Manifest SaleApp**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2aQT.png)

**Manifest RegistryApp**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJcka.png)

Copy-pasting Manifest code gave error, so i upload screenshot.

**Error Logcat**

```
    2022-11-20 03:24:35.323 513-557/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.net.conn.NETWORK_CONDITIONS_MEASURED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
2022-11-20 03:24:35.461 513-1473/? W/ActivityManager: Background start not allowed: service Intent { cmp=com.google.android.apps.messaging/.shared.datamodel.action.execution.ActionExecutorImpl$EmptyService } to com.google.android.apps.messaging/.shared.datamodel.action.execution.ActionExecutorImpl$EmptyService from pid=13113 uid=10119 pkg=com.google.android.apps.messaging startFg?=false
2022-11-20 03:24:35.529 513-1477/? W/ActivityManager: Background start not allowed: service Intent { cmp=com.google.android.apps.messaging/.shared.datamodel.action.execution.ActionExecutorImpl$EmptyService } to com.google.android.apps.messaging/.shared.datamodel.action.execution.ActionExecutorImpl$EmptyService from pid=13113 uid=10119 pkg=com.google.android.apps.messaging startFg?=false
2022-11-20 03:24:36.437 513-557/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.net.conn.NETWORK_CONDITIONS_MEASURED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
2022-11-20 03:24:43.853 513-551/? D/EventSequenceValidator: Transition from ACTIVITY_FINISHED to INTENT_STARTED
2022-11-20 03:24:43.854 513-1785/? I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher cmp=com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity (has extras)} from uid 10137
2022-11-20 03:24:43.877 513-551/? D/EventSequenceValidator: Transition from INTENT_STARTED to ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED
2022-11-20 03:24:44.149 12251-12251/? D/BoundBrokerSvc: onBind: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.feedback.internal.IFeedbackService dat=chimera-action: cmp=com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsBoundBrokerService }
2022-11-20 03:24:44.149 12251-12251/? D/BoundBrokerSvc: Loading bound service for intent: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.feedback.internal.IFeedbackService dat=chimera-action: cmp=com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsBoundBrokerService }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are calling `sendBroadcast`? Is your `Activity` running and in the foreground when the `Service` sends the broadcast? Is `onReceive()` getting called at all?

Comment: Yes I'm sure that I calling `sendBroadcast`. I'm not sure that is `Activity` in the foreground when the `Service` sends the broadcast. I see activity layout on the screen after closing another app, so I think it's running and in the foreground. `OnReceive()` not getting called.

Comment: Is there a better way to return data from service to activity? Activity should request the data and wait until get the response from service.

Comment: This method is fine for sending data from `Service` to `Activity`. There are other methods: You can use a bound `Service` and AIDL, you can use an event bus, you can use `LiveData`, etc.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code. DId you check the logcat? Maybe try looking at the logcat unflitered and see if you see anything the looks suspicous.

Comment: I find something suspicous. I get a fatal exception that does not terminate the app, `android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground(): ServiceRecord{67815bd u0 com.myexample.registryapp/.RegistryService}` after close the another app which intented from service.

Comment: Also I get errors `Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied` and `Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument` but I'm not sure they are related to Broadcast.

Comment: The `RemoteServiceException` is crashing the foreground `Service`, so that might be your problem. You need to make sure that your foreground `Service` is calling `startForeground()` in `onStartCommand()`. The other errors look unrelated to your problem.

Comment: I add notification with `startForeground(notificationId, notification)`, that exception done, but it still dont work. I don't get an error but still broadcast not receive. I'm not sure is it related : `I/system_server: oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4`

Comment: Edit your question and add the manifest for both apps please. It is difficult to understand the problem without more information.

Comment: I edited my code. I dont know is it related but get an error in logcat `BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent`. It happens when I intent from RegistryService to PaymentApp. I can share PaymentApp code if you need but I think it works fine. Service start PaymentApp, then with a button PaymentApp close and we continue with RegistryService.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire content of the error "BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent". There should be a line or more after that message that describes the `Intent`.

Comment: Ok, I edit as you suggest.